# MySQL select a random row per each grouped column value

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am using SAM Broadcaster which separates categories and the songs they contain.

What I want is a list of 5 random artists with a random selection of their songs, no repeat artist.  This is what I have done so far:

---

I have a category named "Classics":

```
select ID from category where name = 'Classics';
```

This returns: 11

So with this I can get a list of all the items in the categorylist:

```
SELECT artist, title 
FROM songlist LEFT OUTER JOIN categorylist on songlist.id = categorylist.songID 
WHERE categorylist.categoryID = 11 ORDER BY RAND();
```

This returns:

- Seals & Crofts - Summer Breeze
- The Doobie Brothers - What A Fool Believes
- Seals & Crofts - Diamond Girl
- Pet Shop Boys - West End Girls
- Men at Work - Be Good Johnny
- Joe Walsh - All Night Long
- Seals & Crofts - Get Closer
- The Tubes - Talk To Ya Later
- The Cars - Bye Bye Love
- Michael Stanley Band - Lover
- The Police - Synchronicity II
- Joe Walsh - A Life Of Illusion
- Michael Stanley Band - He Can't Love You
- Michael Stanley Band - My Town
- Pet Shop Boys - What Have I Done To Deserve This?

Now I want to go 1 step further and group this list by artist and limit 5 BUT I want a random item of each of the titles.  Right now when I group by artist I ALWAYS get the titles in ABC order.  So Seals & Crofts' "Diamond Girl" is always listed when their name shows.  Same with every other group.

The goal is to have a list of 5 random songs from this list with no repeat artists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do the trick (intentionally leaving the category selection out of the way to make it more readable):

```
SELECT artist,
       title
FROM   (SELECT artist,
               title,
               CASE
                 WHEN @artist != artist THEN @rn := 1
                 ELSE @rn := @rn + 1
               end rn,
               @artist := artist
        FROM   (SELECT *
                FROM   songlist
                ORDER  BY Rand()) a,
               (SELECT @rn := 0,
                       @name := NULL) r
        ORDER  BY a.artist) s
WHERE  rn <= 1
ORDER  BY Rand()
LIMIT  5
```

Find a demo here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/135f0/30/0)

Comment: All I had to do is add my join in your query and she works like a charm.  I wish I was barking up the right tree, I feel like I should've been able to do it with a random grouping.  Thanks!